# Get git contributors for a specific branch

Tags: git, github

I'm looking for a way to get the count of *unique* contributors in a GitHub repository, for a specific branch.

The [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/) allows retrieval of a list of contributors, with weekly data of additions, commits, and more. This is more than I need, but I can extract the count from here. However, as stated in the API:

> Computing repository statistics is an expensive operation, so we try to return cached data whenever possible. [...] Give the job a few moments to complete, and then submit the request again.

While it is doable, I would rather get the result in a single operation.

I could also request the HTML page for the repository, and try to parse the HTML to extract the number of contributors, but this does not seem to be an elegant solution.

Another option I looked into was the use of `git log`. Namely, the commands

```
git log --format='%aN' | sort -u | wc -l
git log --format='%aE' | sort -u | wc -l
git log --format='%cN' | sort -u | wc -l
git log --format='%cE' | sort -u | wc -l
```

Unfortunately, the numbers yielded by these commands disagree with the number of contributors displayed on GitHub. They are sometimes much higher, because there are multiple e-mails for the same person, or the same person commits under some variations of their name. For instance, for a specific repository I'm tracking, these commands give me between 60 to 80 authors, while GitHub says there are 34 contributors.

Is there any other more reliable alternative?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably can do is:

1. Get a list of all contributors by iterating through github api

`https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/contributors?page=<number>`

2. Then using your commands `git log --format=.....` Get a list of contributors from your local repo.
3. Join list 2 with list 1 and this should give you an accurate number of contributors.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same query and though there are many options out there, I found this one particularly elegant and simple:

```
git shortlog --summary --numbered --email HEAD --not master
```

(git shortlog -sne HEAD --not master)